# PowerShell Code to Detect Hyper-V Gen 2 VM vs. Gen 1 VM (Run from VM Itself)

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

In a PowerShell script running from a VM, I'd like to programmatically determine if the VM is a generation 1 Hyper-V VM, or if it is a generation 2 Hyper-V VM. Assume the VM is running a version of Windows compatible with running in a Gen 2 VM.

This question is not about detecting Hyper-V. Given that the script is running on a VM and the VM is running on Hyper-V, how do I determine the VM's generation number?

Possible leads:

[Sample C++ MSDN code to query VM Generation ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/virtual-machine-generation-identifier?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - perhaps there is a way to convert this C++ code to C#, then dynamically compile it at runtime using Add-Type? I think this might be the best approach, but it's beyond my skill level.

[VMDE Project on GitHub](https://github.com/hfiref0x/VMDE) - has all kinds of methods for detecting VM platforms, but it's not written in PowerShell, and getting it to work is beyond my skill level

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: I don't get your use case. So, I am really curious as to why would the Gen version be of value? How would your script code be any different?  You are only acting on the OS resources. The version is important on creation of the VM as to the VM specific features available, but not really a thing once it is up, relative to a PowerShell script. As far as the resources you point to, well, sure you can take on the task of converting/refactoring those, and using Add-Type to leverage that,  but that convert/refactor thing is a different topic, not a PS code issue. If you can't, you need to hire it out

Comment: I'm trying to programmatically determine if a VM is a Gen 1 Hyper-V VM because, in that case, Device Guard (Virtualization Based Security) is not supported. Likewise, at the time of writing, all supported Azure VMs are "gen 1" Hyper-V VMs, and they too are unsupported with Device Guard.

Comment: Ah, OK, then why check for Gen# at all, just check for Device Guard feature on your guest. See my update for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the assumption that if the system is a Hyper-V VM and if it is running UEFI (instead of BIOS), then it is a Hyper-V Gen 2 VM. Likewise, if it is a Hyper-V VM not running UEFI, then it must be a Hyper-V Gen 1 VM. At the time of writing, these assumptions are true.

I went on a coding marathon this afternoon and have a **working solution**, most easily read and maintained on my GitHub: https://github.com/franklesniak/PowerShell_Resources/blob/master/Get-HyperVVMGenerationNumberFromWithinVM.ps1

Unfortunately, the code exceeds the allowable limit of a post here on Stack Overflow, so I can't supply the code in this post. But, the function of interest is **Get-HyperVVMGenerationNumberFromWithinVM** and I've included it below, though **it will not run without the prerequisite functions loaded, included in the GitHub link**.

```
#region License
###############################################################################################
# Copyright 2020 Frank Lesniak

# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software
# and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
# restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
# distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
# Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or
# substantial portions of the Software.

# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING
# BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
# NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM,
# DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
###############################################################################################
#endregion License

function Get-HyperVVMGenerationNumberFromWithinVM {
    # Returns an integer indicating the Hyper-V VM generation number of this system
    # Returns 2 if this system is a Hyper-V VM running as a "Generation 2" Hyper-V VM
    # Returns 1 if this system is a Hyper-V VM running as a "Generation 1" Hyper-V VM
    #   Note: Microsoft Virtual Server and Virtual PC VMs can also return 1
    # Returns 0 if this system is a Hyper-V VM, but the generation number could not be
    #   determined due to an error. Usually this would only occur if the VM is Vista/Windows
    #   Server 2008 system and the PowerShell script was run without administrative privileges.
    #   Check the Warning stream for more information.
    #   Note: Microsoft Virtual Server and Virtual PC VMs can also return 0
    # Returns -1 if this system is not a Hyper-V VM
    $boolHyperVVM = Test-ThisSystemIsAHyperVVM
    if ($null -ne $boolHyperVVM) {
        if ($boolHyperVVM) {
            $boolUEFI = Test-UEFISystem
            if ($null -ne $boolUEFI) {
                if ($boolUEFI) {
                    # Hyper-V VM with UEFI
                    # Generation 2
                    2
                } else {
                    # Hyper-V VM not running UEFI
                    # Generation 1
                    1
                }
            } else {
                # Is a Hyper-V VM but could not determine whether UEFI is running
                # Error condition
                0
            }
        } else {
            # Not a Hyper-V VM
            -1
        }
    } else {
        $null
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, your code seems to answer your use case, so, why make this request at all? Unless you were looking for a built-in or simpler way than your coding marathon delivered, or is it you are promoting your solution for the interest of others? Which is not really a thing here, that I am aware of and I've seen posts closed for it. Yet, sharing is a good thing in general. ;-}

Comment: Hey @postanote, I was hoping for a solution that used the Win32 approach mentioned in my question, but when that was looking unlikely (based on my lack of skill working with Win32), I started writing code. I didn't set out to answer my own question, but I eventually did - so I figured why not share my solution.

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Not natively as you have already discovered, but a workaround might be to Invoke to a remote computer running hyper-v, and run the Get-VM cmdlet there to check your guest for the gen number.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'SomeRemoteServerNameWithHyperV' {
    Get-VM -ComputerName 'YourHostName' | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, Generation
}
```

***Update***

Based on your [Device Guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/device-guard/enable-virtualization-based-protection-of-code-integrity) check. Just try this...

```
Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_DeviceGuard –Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The first part of your reply probably won't work for me because some of the VMs are in Azure (so I do not have credentials to the Hyper-V host). I'm interested in your suggestion about querying Device Guard, though... However, I ran it on a system that I know does not support DG and still got results. Can you elaborate on your answer a bit more? What would I be looking for?

Comment: Oh, and I should clarify one point. Windows Server 2019 running in a Hyper-V Gen 2 VM supports Device Guard, but there is some underlying issue with the Secure Launch Configuration sub-setting. See discussion: https://twitter.com/FrankLesniak/status/1286683529296961544?s=20 or if you have an account with the Center for Internet Security, I have a ticket open in the Windows Community. So I also want to detect Gen 2 HV VMs so that I can make sure this particular sub-setting doesn't get applied. DG seems to be a royal mess.