# Is there a programmatic way to determine which application processor architectures are supported?

Tags: windows, powershell, arm, compatibility

I'm writing a set of PowerShell functions that could theoretically be running in an `x86`, `AMD64`, `ARM`, or `ARM64` PowerShell process. The script function will launch a specified executable, but first I'd like to check if the executable's "machine type" is actually supported by the current Windows installation.

Examples:

- Windows Server 2019 can have its WOW64 compatibility layer removed - I'd like to detect that WOW64 is unavailable before attempting to launch an x86 EXE
- Windows 10 on ARM64 supports x86, ARM, and ARM64 executables at the time of writing, but Microsoft is reportedly working on AMD64 (x64) application support through an extension of the WOW subsystem. So, in some future release of Windows, Windows 10 on ARM64 will support AMD64 applications.

Rather than hardcoding a bunch of checks, is there a way to determine whether the native OS or its WOW subsystem can run a given executable?

Ignoring the specifics of the PowerShell language and using pseudocode, the ideal function would be something like:

---

`IsProcessorArchitectureAvailable(strProcessorArchitecture)`

- strProcessorArchitecture would be "x86", "AMD64", "ARM", or "ARM64"
- The function would return True if applications that use the specified processor architecture can run, False otherwise.

---

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about using `Get-CimInstance` with the classes `CIM_OperatingSystem` and `CIM_Processor`?

Comment: Exactly.  Win32_Processor or CIM_Processor may be able to help,  (https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_processor)

Comment: @dan The Win32_Processor returns a whole bunch of information about a system's processor(s). I wasn't able to find any information about the OS' ability to execute code targeted for any given architecture. Which property do you have in mind?

Comment: Not sure why you need to? If the executable fails to start, then it will give an error such as 216 (ERROR_EXE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH).

Comment: On page I linked, in the section labelled Architecture it explains how you can retrieve whether the system is x86, MIPS, Alpha, PowerPC, ia64, x64 using a bit of code.  The main idea is that you retrieve an integer value from Win32_Processor that represents one of those types.  The code is simply `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Architecture`.  There is a lookup table in the code on that page that you can use to translate the code to the term.

Comment: Codes listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IsWow64GuestMachineSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64guestmachinesupported) API can be used to determine if WOW64 is turned off or not:

> Apps that need to determine if WOW64 is turned off or not. For example,
> many apps assume x86-64 systems can always execute x86-32 code at all
> times, everywhere. Note that this ability does not exist on WinPE or
> Xbox, and it is an optional component in Server.

Using this API you can also check for ARM architectures, see [Image File Machine Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/image-file-machine-constants).

There is also [IsWow64Process2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process2) which returns the native architecture of the host system.

To call these API's you would need to P/Invoke with C# from PowerShell.

Full C# Example can be found [here](https://github.com/rweijnen/SharpWow64ApiSet/tree/main) and PowerShell example [here](https://github.com/rweijnen/Posh-Snippets/blob/master/PoshWow64ApiSet).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. It offers tidbits of information based on which a client could fumble together a brittle implementation that sometimes doesn't fail to answer the question that was asked. Doesn't read anything like *"robust"* or *"reliable"* to me.

Comment: I'd like to detect that WOW64 is unavailable was the first part of the question (directly answered), the 2nd part was something like IsProcessorArchitectureAvailable pseudocode which can be directly done with IsWow64Process2. I have provided both C# and PowerShell example code so I feel like I have given a proper answer. I'm happy to improve the answer but fail to see why it wouldn't be robust or reliable so please elaborate if you still think so @IInspectable

Comment: Considering my lack of C# knowledge and especially lack of ability to write Win32 P/Invoke in C#, you got me 98% of the way there. I just submitted a PR to you with some suggested edits (https://github.com/rweijnen/Posh-Snippets/pull/1) that aligns the code a bit more to my purposes. Regardless, I'm going to mark your reply as the answer. Thanks a million!

Comment: PS, @Remko, if you want another Win32 to PowerShell conversion challenge, check out my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092396/powershell-code-to-detect-hyper-v-gen-2-vm-vs-gen-1-vm-run-from-vm-itself. My answer works, but it is not nearly as clean as it could be using the Win32 calls.